# Factoring Algebra Expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I have the below algebra expression:

$$ (x-1)((x-1)^2 - 1) = 6y$$

I'm trying to get the left hand side be $x(x^2-1)$:
$$ x(x^2-1) = 6y \dots$$
Attempt:
$$ (x-1)(x^2-2x) = 6y$$
$$ x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x = 6y$$
I'm stuck here

Comment: You need to simplify this $(x-1)((x-1)^2 - 1) = 6y$?

Comment: I'm trying to make the left hand side be $x(x^2-1) = 6y \dots$ where the dots is the factoring from what it is now.

Comment: I'm trying to convert $(x−1)((x−1)^2−1)$ to $x(x^2-1)$ by factoring out to the $6y$ side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not worry, your algebra is correct.

The problem is that  $$(x-1)((x-1)^2 - 1) = (x-1)(x^2 -2x)=x(x-1)(x-2)$$

is not the same as $$x(x^2-1)=x(x-1)(x+1)$$

Comment: Is there no way to move stuff over to the $6y$ to make the left hand side be $x(x^2-1)$ ?

Comment: No, there is no way.

Answer (score 1):

but it is $$x(x-1)(x+1)=(x-1)(x+1)x=(x-1)(x^2+x)\ne (x-1)(x^2-2x+1-1)$$